# In a container I have text and img tag, how can I get only the text with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I need to get only the text inside this container, but I have a `<img>` with the text, I tried and tried but I don't know how to get only the text. If you see the code below, I only want to get the text inside the `<th>` without the `<img>` tag. Here is the code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="user_head_id">
                ID<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows"></img>
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_name">
                User<img src="images/DownArrow16I.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_mail">
                E-mail<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_nif">
                DNI<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_permission">
                Permissions<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_ban">
                Ban code<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="seleccionable">
        <tr class="tr_users">
            <td class="user_id">'.$myarray[0].'</td>
            <td class="user_name">'.$myarray[1].'</td>
            <td class="user_mail">'.$myarray[2].'</td>
            <td class="user_nif">'.$myarray[3].'</td>
            <td class="user_permission">'.$myarray[4].'</td>
            <td class="user_ban">'.$myarray[5].'</td>';
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would help immensely if you showed us what you've actually tried, even if it isn't working. If your selector is correct to get the right element, then you probably want [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Why not put `p` or a `span` with class around that text and then easily get it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method for getting the text inside an element.The `text( )` method gets the combined text contents of all matched elements.

**Working Demo**

```js
$('th').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="user_head_id">
                ID<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows"></img>
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_name">
                User<img src="images/DownArrow16I.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_mail">
                E-mail<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_nif">
                DNI<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_permission">
                Permissions<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_ban">
                Ban code<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="seleccionable">
        <tr class="tr_users">
            <td class="user_id">'.$myarray[0].'</td>
            <td class="user_name">'.$myarray[1].'</td>
            <td class="user_mail">'.$myarray[2].'</td>
            <td class="user_nif">'.$myarray[3].'</td>
            <td class="user_permission">'.$myarray[4].'</td>
            <td class="user_ban">'.$myarray[5].'</td>';
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: using the .text() you're actually scaping the img tag as text string, and not solving the problem of him...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that function!

Comment: because the alert method scape the html sintaxe

Comment: @MarvinMedeiros Please do not down vote unnecessarily.If you are down voting  have the courtesy to add a comment why you are down voting.

Comment: @MarvinMedeiros Please make sure you are correct before telling something.  
`because the alert method scape the html sintaxe` I have changed it to `console.log`. Check the demo. If you are convinced then remove the down vote.

Comment: @Senén Sometimes it happens `:)`. Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, cuting the string:

```js
$('thead th').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text().split('<img')[0];
    console.log(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="user_head_id">
                ID<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows"></img>
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_name">
                User<img src="images/DownArrow16I.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_mail">
                E-mail<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_nif">
                DNI<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_permission">
                Permissions<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
            <th id="user_head_ban">
                Ban code<img src="images/DownArrow16A.ico" class="order_arrows">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But the better aproach is you putting your text in a `p` or a `span` tag and setting an id to it.